# Using OnClientClick and OnClick events?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, docusignapi

I have situation where a client goes to a website to complete a webform and upon submission/click of an asp button performs two acts:

1) runs a jquery script that opens an iframe for an embedded form to a thirdparty service that gets information via a url created by the jquery also (in this case docusign)

2) runs a method to insert specific data about the submission to an sql database table.

It is my understanding that the OnClient has to fire prior to the OnClick as well as some sort of return/postback if I understand correctly is needed to fire the onclick/severside method. So my difficulty has been trying understand how best to get the serverside method to fire... Any thought would be greatly appreciated. At first thought adding some sort of return true function but do not see how this would work. Thanks for any input and forward guidance.

So currently my asp button OnClientClick calls the following jquery that opens an iframe... I cannot figure how to also have it postback to cause the Onclick event to fire as well? Unless I can have the jquery fire/called from behind?

(jquery used to open/embed form)

```
function $$(elem) {return document.getElementById(elem);} //simple id reference

//Powerform/Iframe Specifics

number_messages = 0;
var last_id = "";

function check_messages() { //check for messages from iframe
if (location.hash != last_id) {
    last_id = location.hash;
    number_messages++;
    last_id = last_id.replace("_"," ");
    last_id = last_id.substr(1);
    last_id = last_id.substr(0,last_id.indexOf("&"));
    var message_color;
    var extra_text;
    if(last_id=="Signing Complete" || last_id=="Viewing Complete"){
        message_color="green";
        extra_text = "";
    }else{
        message_color="red";
        extra_text = "<p style='text-align:center'><button type='form.button' onclick='window.location=\"embedded.html\"' style='display:inline;'>Reload form?</button></p>";
    }
    document.getElementById("powerform").innerHTML = "<center><h3 style='color:"+message_color+";border:none;font-size:20px;text-align:center;'>" + last_id + "</h3><br/>"+extra_text+"</center>";
}
}

function open_embeddedform(form) {
var form_url = "https://demo.docusign.net/MEMBER/PowerFormSigning.aspx";
form_url += "?PowerFormId=" + $$("Powerformid").value;
form_url += "&UserName=" + $$("UserName").value;
form_url += "&UserEmail=" + $$("UserEmail").value;

    //alert(form_url);

$$("powerform").innerHTML = '<iframe id="document" src="' + form_url + '" border="0"></iframe>';
}

setInterval(check_messages, 200);
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to wade through. Could you reduce it to the minimum needed to explain the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could you run the server side as a PageMethod or Web Service which the client side sends an Ajax request to with the information about the submission? That way you could also return a success to the user to display some completion message.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure whatever your `Onclientclick` calls returns true.  Check out [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727811/onclick-event-not-firing-when-onclientclick-returns-true) for more detail.

Comment: I have tried adding something of this nature at the end of the function but it does not want return true. I am not sure if it relates to the iframe and use of another server/url that has its own set of events I am not privy to. I do appreciate the link and assistance. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it with a local function that returns true just to make sure the onclientclick it fires as u expect?  Also make sure you only have one form tag when using web forms.

Comment: I have..but no luck. Tried adding it into the current function, separating it into two functions, even tried - which is most likely poor programming - to create a separate invisible button and have it triggered but no luck as the iframe stops/does  not load or the serverside method does not fire. Thanks again for following up with another idea/thought. Cheers